# How to add a copy of an object instead of reference to it

Tags: f#

So - I am doping a loop in F# with some complex logic in it so I am using a System.Collections.Generic.List so I can add to it in the loop.

What I am finding though - is that when I add an item to the list - it still somehow has a reference to the variable so when I change the "currentPostCodeRange" variable, then all of the previous additions to the list are changed as well!  is there a way I can assign a "copy"  of the variable somehow so it doesn't reference every single item..?

```
let postcodeRanges: System.Collections.Generic.List<Postcode.PostcodeRange> 
        = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Postcode.PostcodeRange>()
    let mutable currentPostCodeRange: Postcode.PostcodeRange = { RangeType = Postcode.RangeType.Normal; From="0001"; To="0001" }
```

Loop:

```
        for postCode in 1 .. 9999 do
         .....
            if nextPostCodeisRural <> thisPostCodeisRural then
            // this is the last one in this Range
                currentPostCodeRange.To <- thisPostCodeString
                postcodeRanges.Add(currentPostCodeRange)
         .... etc, other logic
```

Comment: Could you describe what are you trying to do in general? There is a nicer way to do this using immutable records and higher-order functions, but for that we need to know the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to copy a record in F# is with a [copy and update record expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/copy-and-update-record-expressions). I strongly recommend against adding mutable objects to collections, though, precisely because it creates the [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)) problem you're seeing here. However, if you're determined to do it, you can add a copy like this:

```ml
postcodeRanges.Add({ currentPostCodeRange with To = currentPostCodeRange.To })
```

You have to include at least one field in the expression, so in this case, I've explicitly copied the `To` field, and implicitly copied the rest. It doesn't matter which one you pick.

Again, I strongly recommend against this sort of design. I think you're better off in the long run using a [scan](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#scan), or some other functional technique.

Comment: thank you .  Yes I would like to go fully functional - I just can't quite get my head around creating ranges from a sequence based on some logic.  Too many years of sequential / OOP  :-)